# export 'useMutation' (imported as 'useMutation') was not found in 'react-admin'

Tags: react-admin

I have error in console when try to compile react admin
Version in package.json - "react-admin": "^4.2.2"
[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDzcH.png)

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyQmO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-admin v4 no longer exports useQuery / useMutation.

You may want to use useCreate / useUpdate.

If you want to import useQuery / useMutation, you can import them from '`react-query`'

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usequery-and-usemutation